# Run Error in Java...Scanner closed?

Tags: java

So I have this code and it's supposed to read data from a file called "Numbers.txt". In this file, it is simply just 2003 lines of decimal numbers. The goal of the program is to read this file and make calculations. First I had to get the mean, which I've managed to do, but the problem is I have to now go back in and get the standard deviation. It compiles fine but I get a run error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1115)
    at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:1379)
    at StatsDemo.main(StatsDemo.java:49)
```

This is my code:

```
File rf2 = new File("Numbers.txt"); //reconnect to the FileReader object passing it the filename
    Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(rf2);//reconnect to the BufferedReader object passing it the FileReader object.
    sum = 0; //reinitialize the sum of the numbers
    count = 0; //reinitialize the number of numbers added
    //priming read to read the first line of the file
    while (inputFile.hasNext()) //loop that continues until you are at the end of the file
    {
     difference = inputFile.nextDouble() - mean; //convert the line into a double value and subtract the mean
        sum += Math.pow(difference,2); //add the square of the difference to the sum
        count++; //increment the counter
        if (inputFile.hasNextDouble())
        inputFile.nextLine(); //read a new line from the file
    }
  inputFile.close(); //close the input file
    stdDev = Math.sqrt(sum/count); //store the calculated standard deviation
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I got a similar (but not the same) one from the mean calculation earlier, but the resolve for that doesn't work for this. Any ideas?

**After changing to inputFile2...**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1115)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1510)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
at StatsDemo.main(StatsDemo.java:51)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `inputFile` with `inputFile2` because it's the `Scanner` object.

Comment: --- Nevermind my previous post. I'm an idiot. Resolved. Time for bed. Thanks folks.

Comment: its okk dear..My pleasure to help u

Answer (score 2):

Your `Scanner` is called `inputFile2` not `inputFile`.

Answer (score 1):

Rename `inputFile` to `inputFile2` in code `while (inputFile.hasNext())`

Answer (score 0):

Your Scanner object is with inputFile2 and you are using inputFile as a scanner object. I am surprised how is your code running without any compile errors. In case you have another file which is associated with inputFile Scanner object for which you have not provided code above, just check the file and closing of that reference where you are flushing the inputFile object. Otherwise, correct your code as below:

```
File rf2 = new File("Numbers.txt"); //reconnect to the FileReader object passing it the filename
    Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(rf2);//reconnect to the BufferedReader object passing it the FileReader object.
    sum = 0; //reinitialize the sum of the numbers
    count = 0; //reinitialize the number of numbers added
    //priming read to read the first line of the file
    while (inputFile2.hasNext()) //loop that continues until you are at the end of the file
    {
     difference = inputFile2.nextDouble() - mean; //convert the line into a double value and subtract the mean
        sum += Math.pow(difference,2); //add the square of the difference to the sum
        count++; //increment the counter
        if (inputFile2.hasNextDouble())
        inputFile2.nextLine(); //read a new line from the file
    }
  inputFile2.close(); //close the input file
    stdDev = Math.sqrt(sum/count); //store the calculated standard deviation
```